# Remove String from list if certain character missing

Tags: java, string

I have a list of words ["home", "shop", "salmon", "time"] and I have a scrambled String "ahlowemr". I want to check if each word in the list has characters from this scrambled String and remove the word from list if it doesn't contain all the characters.

In this example, less "home", the remaining 3 Strings should be removed. I tried to loop as follows but it doesn't allow me to check characters. And I am nesting loops which I think is not a good idea. Is there any way around this?

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
myList.add("home");
myList.add("shop");
myList.add("salmon");
myList.add("time");

String scrambled = "ahlowemr";

for(String s : myList){
    for(char c : scrambled.toCharArray()){
        if(!s.contains(c)){ //doesn't allow character c
            myList.remove(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are `list` and `myList` really the same? If so, you there are other issues with your code.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Edited. They are the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to remove items from a list while you iterate it, you should use an `Iterator`, also, the `contains(...)` method expects a `String`, not a `char`.

Here is what you can do:

```
for(Iterator<String> it = myList.iterator(); it.hasNext();){
    String s = it.next();
    for(char c : scrambled.toCharArray()){
        if(!s.contains(String.valueOf(c))){ 
            it.remove();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does lets me loop with no issue but my list ends up empty. I reversed the check where I check  scrambled.contains instead against s.toCharArray. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
myList.add("home");
myList.add("shop");
myList.add("salmon");
myList.add("time");

String scrambled = "ahlowemr";

for(int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
    for(char c : scrambled.toCharArray()){
        if(!myList.get(i).contains(c.toString())){ //doesn't allow character in that position
            // There is a simple way using a regex or maybe a hashtable
            myList.remove(s);
            break; // break will jump into the next list value
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) solution for completeness:

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();

myList.add("home");
myList.add("shop");
myList.add("salmon");
myList.add("time");

String scrambled = "ahlowemr";

myList = myList.stream()
        .filter(s -> scrambled.chars()
                .allMatch(c -> s.contains(String.valueOf((char) c))))
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList<String>::new));
```